# Switching between DVORAK and QWERTY via command line in Solaris 10

Tags: keyboard, unix, keyboard-layout, solaris, solaris-10

I'm looking for a quick way to switch between DVORAK and QWERTY layouts in Solaris 10.  I'd like to be able to do it solely through the command line and rather quickly. I see I might be able to do this with `setxkbmap` but I don't plan on always having this installed on the Solaris system.  Is there another quick way to switch layouts? Or a quick way to install setxkbmap on Solaris 10? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setxkbmap` is included in Solaris 10 9/10 and available in patches for older Solaris 10 releases:

- SPARC: 143771-01
- x86/x64: 143772-01

Comment: Hmm, I just did a fresh installation of Solaris 10 u8 (10/09) and I get "command not found" when I attempt to use setxkbmap.

Comment: That's because that's older than the Solaris 10 9/10 (S10 U9) release it was added in.   (Yes, the two releases just happen to have confusingly similar names due to their release dates in October 2009 and September 2010.)

Comment: An alternative would be using xmodmap with the suitable keymap tables.